# google map is not loading properly, zoom is not working in bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open a google map in a bootstrap modal but the map is not loading properly also the map zoom is not working.
I am using iframe code for google map.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I am adding this jquery code $('#mymodal').on('shown', function () {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}); but still not working.

Comment: You need to provide the relevant code as either a mockup on a site like Bootply/JSFiddle/CodePen/JSBin, as well as include the code here if you want help. How can anyone help you debug code we can't see?